# Tcl error : invalid command name tcl_findLibrary

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, tkinter, windows-7-x64

This error appears when I type the following commands (using iPython)`Tkinter.Tk()`, `%pylab`, `plot` ..... or run pylab in general but `import pylab` doesn't fire any error.

```
Tcl error : invalid command name tcl_findLibrary
```

As I know Python installers for Windows already contain a full Tcl/Tk installation so i didn't use anything other than the regular Python installer.

The OS is x64 but I use the x32 installer as some extra python libraries don't have x64 version.

Python 2.7.5 x32 
OS: Windows7-x64

Comment: There must be something missing. Check [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/tk-tcl-td2217540.html). I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I saw that link before, but unfortunately it didn't work but for the word soft-reset I've tried them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, I needed to remove `tcl_library` and `tk_library` from the environment variables. 
Although before putting them pylab fired an error saying something like it couldn't find some tcl files, and putting them solved that error but fired this one.