# (invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary") Python matplotlib.pyplot error

Tags: python, matplotlib, tcl, python-3.4, windows-server-2008-r2

Although related to the problem discussed Here: [Tcl error : invalid command name tcl_findLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563174/tcl-error-invalid-command-name-tcl-findlibrary)

That solution does not solve my error. That solution says to remove the env variables:

> I've figured it out, I needed to remove tcl_library and tk_library
>   from the environment variables. Although before putting them pylab
>   fired an error saying something like it couldn't find some tcl files,
>   and putting them solved that error but fired this one.

Assuming that by Environment Variables, they are referring to Windows Variables, they do not exist on my machine.

I am having trouble generating plots with Matplotlib due to some tcl errors.

Environment is:
Python 3.4.1 + Windows 2008 R2 Virtual Machine

The Below Python Code Generates the following Error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [10,11,12,13]
plt.plot(X, Y, linewidth = 0.5)
plt.ylabel('Data')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.show

Error: Invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"
```

I had other tcl errors before this that I was able to get around by manually moving tcl files and folders into different directories.(i.e. init.tcl not found)

I see several problems with Pythons Tkinter on here, but my error is with Matplotlib. Any thoughts?

Comment: tcl_findLibrary: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1701

Comment: The problem is that your Python installation is doing something to make the embedded Tcl system fail to initialise correctly. Since the embedded Tcl is supposed to be able to do that _if no environment variables are set at all_ — the various `TCL_*` variables are mainly for testing environments — it indicates a misconfiguration on the Python side.